# A class of functions dense in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f\in L^2([0,1],\Sigma,\mu)$. Is the class of all $$f=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i (\chi_{A_i}-\chi_{[0,1]/A_i} )$$$A_i\in \Sigma$ to be  dense in $L^2([0,1],\Sigma,\mu)$?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $g\perp (\chi_{[0,x)}-\chi_{[x,1]})$ for all $x\in [0,1].$ Then $\int_0^x g = \int_x^1g, x \in [0,1].$ By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, $g(x)=-g(x)$ for a.e. $x.$ Thus $g=0$ a.e. This shows that the subspace you defined is dense in $L^2.$

Comment: Hi, is it diffrentiation theorem and approach also apply for other measurable space if [0,1] is replaced by  X and  with other measure?